# Is there a gnuplot configuration file?

Tags: configuration, gnuplot

I am trying to setup gnuplot so that at startup I always have the comma as datafile separator, with the following command:

```
set datafile separator ","
```

Unfortunately, it looks like there's no concept of a `.gnuplotrc` in gnuplot. At least I didn't find anything in the man page, and I don't have [strace](https://strace.io/) on this machine so I cannot see by myself. I am tired of typing the command every time I fire up gnuplot. Does anybody have a good solution for this? Note that using `load` does not solve my issue: I would still have to type the `load` command.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In fact, there is a gnuplot startup file: it's called .gnuplot, and should do exactly what you want. For details, try running `help startup` within an interactive gnuplot session.

> #### 18 Start-up
>
> When **gnuplot** is run, it looks for an initialization file to load. This file is called **.gnuplot** on Unix and AmigaOS systems, and **GNUPLOT.INI** on other systems. If this file is not found in the current directory, the program will look for it in the HOME directory (under AmigaOS, Atari(single)TOS, MS-DOS, Windows and OS/2, the environment variable **GNUPLOT** should contain the name of this directory; on Windows NT, it will use **USERPROFILE** if GNUPLOT isn’t defined). Note: if NOCWDRC is defined during the installation, **gnuplot** will not read from the current directory.
>
> If the initialization file is found, **gnuplot** executes the commands in it. These may be any legal **gnuplot** commands, but typically they are limited to setting the terminal and defining frequently-used functions or variables.

http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-6900018

Answer (score 5):

For the new version of gnuplot try this:

See the path of the *gnuplotrc* file using the command within gnuplot:

```
show loadpath
```

Then just open the file and add the commands you want.

Here is more info from the the [documentation][1] of the latest version(**4.6**):

When gnuplot is run, it ﬁrst looks for a system-wide initialization ﬁle named **gnuplotrc**. The location of this ﬁle is determined when the program is built and is reported by *show loadpath*. The program then looks in the user’s HOME directory for a ﬁle called **.gnuplot** on Unix-like systems or **GNUPLOT.INI** on other systems. (Windows and OS/2 will look for it in the directory named in the environment variable GNUPLOT; Windows will use USERPROFILE if GNUPLOT is not deﬁned). Note: The program can be conﬁgured to look ﬁrst in the current directory, but this is not recommended because it is bad security practice.

Answer (score 0):

Generally on windows, the main configuration file GNUPLOT.INI is loaded by a command in gnuplotrc. This way you can change the location of GNUPLOT.INI

But in addition to GNUPLOT.INI, there is also a separate configuration file for the widows terminal. It is called wgnuplot.ini and it can be found in the  %APPDATA% directory. You can create it manually if it does not exist.

This file is updated automatically when you select "update .." at the bottom of the right-click menu of the terminal console. This way, you can change e.g. the font size of that terminal.