# Gnuplot: How do you load a custom command?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm looking for a way to load a custom command to my gnuplot sessions. Often after playing around with a plot I want to output it to PDF, and continue working. This will look like:

```
set terminal pdf
set output   'somefilename.pdf'
replot
set terminal qt
replot
```

Currently the best I can do is put that in a separate file with the file name a variable instead of a string, define said variable in my session, then load said file. I'm wondering if I can load this script as a command that takes an argument, so I can do something like

```
exportpdf "myfile.pdf"
```

Comment: you can define custom commands which are loaded on startup - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1200530/5351549

Comment: @ewcz where does it say there how to define a custom command? The at init part is less important.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30334657/2604213

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your your current method is already pretty good, but if you want you can fine-tune it a little bit:

1. If you are willing to keep storing the name of the file in a gnuplot variable FILENAME, then you can circumvent the need of an external file by using macros:

   ```
   exportpdf="set term push; set term pdf; set output FILENAME; replot; set output; set term pop"
   ```

   You can then save your current figure by executing

   ```
   @exportpdf
   ```
2. If you want to give the filename as an argument you can create a script file `exportpdf.gp`

   ```
   set term push
   set term pdf
   set output ARG1
   replot
   set output
   set term pop
   ```

   and define the string

   ```
   exportpdf='call "exportpdf.gp"'
   ```

   for example in your startup file. Then you can save your current figure to filename simply by executing

   ```
   @exportpdf "filename.pdf"
   ```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to define a custom "function", you could first construct the appropriate command and then `eval`uate it:

```
plotPdf(fname) = eval(sprintf("set terminal pdf;set output '%s';replot;set terminal qt;replot;", fname))
```

this definition can be then conveniently placed in the Gnuplot startup script so that it is automatically available

Comment: I'm getting invalid command when trying `plotPdf` no arguments, `plotPdf('something')` or `plotPdf 'something'`.

Comment: I'm GnuPlot version 5.0 patch level 5 if it matters.

Comment: @kabanus and could you try to execute directly `set terminal pdf;set output '%s';replot;set terminal qt;replot;` with `%s` replaced with the argument you tried before? just to see which part fails...

Comment: I wasn't clear - the error is is that plotPdf itself is invalid. Your line itself is fine. I tried print plotPdf('abc'), but then it complains eval is not a function, though it works as is when input directly to the command line -`eval(sprintf("set terminal pdf;set output '%s';replot;set terminal qt;replot;", 'abc'))` works directly.

Comment: `x() = eval(sprintf("set terminal pdf;set output '%s';replot;set terminal qt;replot;", 'abc'));` complains x is an invalid command, but `x = eval(sprintf("set terminal pdf;set output '%s';replot;set terminal qt;replot;", 'abc'));` complains eval is an undefined function.