# How to set default path directory for gnuplot on mac

Tags: gnuplot

I store data on desktop, now I use "set loadpath" each time to plot, but this method is too inefficient. Is there any more efficient way?

Comment: This already has an answer. [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200463/gnuplot-configuration-file) out. The details in the answer guide to to the fine points in case you are on Mac/Linux/Windows systems.